# Javascript: Show XML If Word Is In URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, blogger

I'm wanting to make changes to a certain page. Specifically the "Preview" page in Blogger when you go to preview a post. As far as I know there is no conditional statement for it.

The preview page URL looks something like this: `http://mydomain.com/b/post-preview?token=###############`

So I'm trying to use javascript to say "hey, if `/b/post-preview` is in the URL, then show hide this element".

I have been unsuccessful. This is my attempt(and there are others):

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
         if ((window.location.href) === '/b/post-preview') {
           $('homepage-slider-section').css('display', 'none');
         }
     });
```

Comment: `if (location.href.indexOf('/b/post-preview') > -1) {`

Comment: This didn't seem to work, nor did it throw any errors in my console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div id="toBeOrNotToBe">To be or not to be, that is the question</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log(window.location.href);
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('fiddle') !== -1) {
        $('#toBeOrNotToBe').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DCbKs/)